# Passing a class method to onscreenclick in python

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I tried implementing the same in a class and it throws an error

```
class Lumber:
    def doclick(x,y):
        print(str(x) + "" + str(y))
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x,y)
        turtle.pendown()
        self.drawBark()

    mainScreen.onscreenclick(fun = doclick)
```

Please suggest a way to call the doclick method. I want everything inside my class

Answer (score 1):

Does the following meet your needs?

```
import turtle

mainScreen = turtle.Screen()

class Lumber:
    def doclick(self, x, y):
        print(str(x), str(y))
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.goto(x, y)
        turtle.pendown()
        self.drawBark()

    def drawBark(self):
        pass

    mainScreen.onscreenclick(fun=lambda x, y: lumber_instance.doclick(x, y))

lumber_instance = Lumber()

turtle.done()
```

Or do you want every Lumber instance to add it's own onscreenclick handler?

Comment: Any way to disable the onscreenclick once my work is done on the screen?

Comment: @user3876764, you should be able to do mainScreen.onscreenclick(None) to turn off the handler.